# Add rows in multiple columns to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Hey I want to add values to a df in R.

For every row I have a vector with 10 strings which I create iteratively for every row. Looks like this for two rows:

```
row1 = c("ID1", "ID4", "ID7", "ID12", "ID19", "ID22", "ID24", "ID37", "ID42", "ID49")
row2 = c("ID2", "ID44", "ID67", "ID72", "ID79", "ID82", "ID84", "ID87", "ID92", "ID99")
```

I want to add them do a df looking like this:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Now I want to create the columns (once at the start I guess?) so the final df looks like this:

| Column_A | Column_B | ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 | ID_4 | ID_5 | ID_6 | ID_7 | ID_8 | ID_9 | ID_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | ID_1 | ID_4 | ID_7 | ID_12 | ID_19 | ID_22 | ID_24 | ID_37 | ID_42 | ID_49 |
| Second | row | ID_2 | ID_44 | ID_67 | ID_72 | ID_79 | ID_82 | ID_84 | ID_87 | ID_92 | ID_99 |

I think it would make sense to create the columns before filling them with the vectors because I have more rows in my data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need data.frame(Column_A = c("First", "Second"), Column_B = c("row", "row")) to be any size, e.g. 10 rows? or 1000 rows? And First, Second, Third, Fourth etc to be automatically set?

Comment: first you bind the rows with rbind: `rbind(row1, row2)` then you paste them to the dataframe. All together is like: `df<-cbind(df, rbind(row1, row2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
library("tidyverse")
# get your data into a list (this can have as many rows as you like)
row1 = c("ID1", "ID4", "ID7", "ID12", "ID19", "ID22", "ID24", "ID37", "ID42", "ID49")
row2 = c("ID2", "ID44", "ID67", "ID72", "ID79", "ID82", "ID84", "ID87", "ID92", "ID99")
rows <- list(row1, row2)

#column bind the first two columns with the list
cbind(
   data.frame(Column_A = c("First", "Second"),
           Column_B = c("row", "row")),
   map(rows, ~ c(a=.x)) %>% 
     bind_rows() %>%
     set_names(paste0("ID_",seq(1,10)))
)
```